# Gensim Doc2Vec getting the doc tags from the Concatenated model

Tags: python, model, gensim, doc2vec

I'm trying to replicate Mikolov's work of PV-DM + PV-DBOW. He says that both algorithms should be used in order to get better results. For this reason I'm trying to train the model and then give the document tags to t-SNE.
Using Gensim's Doc2Vec I can get the document tags with `docvecs.vectors_docs`, but the concatenated structure doesn't appear to have the document tags of the joint model. It is still treating the models as separate entities.
(This I can see from the variable explorer)

I'm also using the `ConcatenatedDoc2Vec` from gensim.

Can anyone help me? Is there a way I can get the document tags from the concatenated new entity and not the individual ones?

Answer (score 2):

Be warned that many have tried to reproduce the reported 'Paragraph Vector' results using concatenated PV-DBOW and PV-DM+dm_concat vectors without success. (For example, Mikolov himself [reports being unable to reproduce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/word2vec-toolkit/Q49FIrNOQRo/J6KG8mUj45sJ) the exact numbers that he says co-author Le contributed to the paper.)

The `ConcatenatedDoc2Vec` class is just a thin wrapper to join two models you've already trained separately, for the purposes of vector-lookup-by-tag (`__getitem__()` indexed access) and combined inference. (It's a mere [10 lines of code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/2024be9053094fbb2e765b9a06b9dc580f55c505/gensim/test/test_doc2vec.py).)

To make this post-training join sensible, those two models should have been trained with the exact same documents/tags in the exact same order.

So if you need a list of tags, ask either model separately.

If you need some other combination of the two models – such as a single large array including all concatenated vectors – you'd have to construct that yourself, perhaps using `numpy`'s `hstack` method.

You can see my notebook trying to reproduce some of the paper's results inside the `gensim` `docs/notebooks` directory, or view online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb